# Changing package names on Google API console

Tags: android, google-maps, package

I recently created an app that uses multiple Google API's, mainly Google Maps and Google Places.

When I first created the app I just used a random package name that didnt have any meaning. Now that the app is ready for release I have changed all of the package names to actually mean something. Will this effect the Google API's I have used? I.e will I have to change the package names to match the app? I have already changed the package names in the console to match the app however I now get an authorization error and the maps dont work. The error is basically telling me to change the package name back to the old one.

What should I do? Can I keep the old package names in the API console or will this become a problem later on?

Answer (score 0):

So I worked out that although I had changed the name of the actual packages I hadnt changed the `applicationId` in the gradle, I updated this to the new package name and now the API's work fine, be sure to sync the gradle, clean and rebuild the project to get it working